# What is 'reigns' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read the following sentence from [this source](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/06/ui-vs-ux-whats-the-difference/):

> UI is the saddle, the stirrups, and the **reigns**. UX is the feeling you get being able to ride the horse, and rope your cattle.

I got stuck in the meaning of a word 'reigns'.

As per [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reign_1?q=reign), 'reign' means a period of somebody as an in charge or a ruler.

So, how it fits here in this sentence? What is 'reigns' in this context?

Thank You.

Comment: It's a mis-spelling of or typo for *reins*, which are the leather straps tied to the bit inside then horse's mouth, which allow you to guide him (similar to a steering wheel in a car, except a car doesn't have a mind of its own, and can't ... ahem ... disagree with you on which direction to go).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but, I shall wait for other answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dan Bron is correct: It is a misspelling of "reins". The author is attempting to make an analogy between UI and proper and necessary horse-riding equipment.

[image: riding equipment]

On a side note, the writing on that original article you sourced was atrocious.

Comment: Stephie, thanks! I have been up for over 24 hours and it is really starting to affect me. : (

Comment: Good point about the article: it's probably not a good source for a beginner to learn English from—though, to be fair, it only has a few overt mistakes, there's far worse, and it's actually a representative example of a certain common style. A funny thing is that the author was _trying_ to say that UX reigns and UI is one of its humble subjects. :)

Comment: That was my first thought - monarch-subject reference. But he names 3 gear and their essentialness to a good horse riding experience- akin to you need good UI for a great UX. (It's actually a beautiful and ingenious metaphor. He uses metaphors copiously.) In any event, it's a blog post and I won't be a "Nazi" on style, tone, or punctuation. But he is missing words, his verbs and subjects don't always agree, his tenses don't always match, and he has trouble carrying a thought through a sentence. I actually thought he was not a native speaker. But you are right- there is much worse out there. :(